# Receiving multiple nack notifications for Unregistered Android Devices from FCM | Java

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We maintain a table in MySQL of all gcmids to which we push notifications. Over time, some may expire as the user may uninstall the application or overload it with another version. However it might have been expired, when we try to send a push notification to these devices, FCM responds with a **"nack"** message with **DEVICE_UNREGISTERED** or a similar error code. Using this information, I am removing this gcmid from our database.

But the problem is that I am receiving many more notifications for each message_id. I have added a SyncStanzaListener to the **XMPP connection** which listens and passes on to my service if it's a nack message. And as a result of this, the CPU is spiking because there's a shitload of messages to handle. A machine had died on production because of this.

I have also tried sending **"ack"** message to this particular gcmid and the message id acknowledging that I have received it. I'm still, receiving the same message over and over again.

Any ideas?

I have tried storing all the message ids in redis with a ttl. But the thing is, I'm not supposed to receiving these many acks for a particular expired gcmid that too with the same message id?! I sometimes receive upto 30 acks with the same message id.